# T is a linear map from V to V and $T^2$=T. V is a vector space of dimension 2.T≠0 and T≠I .

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

T is a linear map from V to V and $T^2$=T. V is a vector space of dimension 2.T≠0  and T≠I . Show that there exists a basis of V with respect to which the matrix of T is $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $

Comment: The minimal polynomial is $X^2-X$ (why?). Its roots tell you the eigenvalues. Use them to dhow that the above is its diagonal form.

Comment: is there any other way????

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with the minimal polynomial or just uncomfortable? What's your background? Do you know how to diagonalize a matrix?

Comment: just unfaimiliar with minimal polynomial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually exercise from Hoffman, Kuntze and solutions are available online.

Here is my aproach:
Let $e_0, e_1$ be some vectors that make basis for V.
Consider rank of T:

1. $rank(T) = 0$, in this case ofc $T = 0$
2. $rank(T) = 2$

   T is not singular, so image of linearly independent set is linearly independent, that
   means $Te_0, Te_1$  are independent and are basis for V since T: V->V.

   $T(Te_0) = Te_0, T(Te_1) = Te_1$, so in the ordered basis $Te_0, Te_1$, T is $I$
   matrix. That means T is identity function.
3. $rank(T) = 1$

   To show that

   > there exists a basis of V with respect to which the matrix of T is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

   We need to find two linearly independent vectors from V $x_0, x_1$, for which holds $Tx_0 = x_0, Tx_1 = 0$

   Let $v_0$ be choosen that it is equal to nonzero vector from set $T(\{e_0, e_1\})$ - this is possible since $rank(T)\neq 0$ - and $v_1$ to be complement of $\{v_0\}$ to basis.

   Since $rank(T) = 1$,
   $\alpha Tv_0 =  Tv_1$ for some scalar $\alpha$.

   $v_0$ and $v_1 - \alpha v_0$ are linearly independent, bc $v_0$ and $v_1$ are independent, and $T(v_0) = v_0, T(v_1 - \alpha v_0) = T(v_1) - \alpha T(v_0) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

The minimal polynomial divides any polynomial that $T$ satisfies.  But $T$ satisfies $x^2-x=0$.  Since $T\ne0,I$, the minimal polynomial is $x^2-x$.  Thus the eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$.  This implies $T$ is diagonalizable, with diagonalization equal to $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

Every vector $x$ may be written as
$$
               x = Tx + (I-T)x.
$$
Note that $y=Tx$ satisfies $Ty=y$ and $z=(I-T)x$ satisfies $Tz=0$. There must be a non-zero $y$ and a non-zero $z$ by assumption. $\{ y,z \}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors because $\alpha y + \beta z=0$ implies
$$
                   0= T(\alpha y + \beta z) = \alpha y \implies \alpha =0 \\
                   0=(I-T)(\alpha y+\beta z) = \beta z \implies \beta = 0.
$$
So $\{ y, z \}$ is a basis.